# What function does a submit button call?

Tags: html, css

I want to create my custom submit button. So I need to know what javascript function does the input type submit button call? I don't want a css customized submit button if possible.

Comment: Going to need a little more information in order to help with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Case your HTML Looks like this:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="destination.html">
  <input id="sub_Button" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="mySubmitFunction();" />
</form>
```

Do you mean **JavaScript**?

```
document.myform.submit();
```

Or **JQuery**?

```
$("#myform").submit();
```